Recreate/Replace Type generated vis Reflection.Emit
I've created a dynamic Type similarly to how it is done in this answer. I'd like to be able to recreate/replace this type at runtime, but the only way I found to do so would be via unloading the whole AppDomain. Unfortunatly AppDomains aren't a thing anymore in .NET 8, so how would I approach this now?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/reflection/collectible-assemblies
